# How do I get data from dict using xpath (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get vendor id from this restaurant page using xpath but I don't know how to get that cause it's inside dictionary. And this is what I tried `//*[@class="vendor"]` then confused

```
<section class ="vendor" data-vendor="{"id":20707,"name":"Beard Papa\u0027s (Novena)","code":"x1jg","category":"Dessert,Bakery and Cakes","is_active":true,"timezone":"Asia\/Singapore","available_in":"2020-11-11T10:00:00+0800","city_id":1,"latitude":1.320027,"longitude":103.843897,"is_pickup_available":true,"is_delivery_available":true,"url_key":"beard-papas-novena","ddt":30,"chain":{"id":1992,"name":"Beard Papa","url_key":"beard-papa","is_accepting_global_vouchers":true,"code":"ck0vb","main_vendor_code":"v3lv"},"rating":4.6,"review_number":224,"minOrder":0,"deliveryFee":0,"is_promoted":false,"is_premium":false,"toppings":[],"accepts_instructions":true,"category_quantity":3,"loyalty_program_enabled":false,"loyalty_percentage_amount":0,"has_delivery_provider":true,"vertical":"restaurants","is_preorder_enabled":true,"is_vat_visible":true}">
```

Comment: Checkout https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html. You could load the json string and then get the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way (as already pointed by [booleantrue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14335262/booleantrue) will be to `import json` and next:

```
data_vendor = response.xpath('//section[@class="vendor"]/@data-vendor').get()
data_vendor = json.loads(data_vendor)
vendor_id = data_vendor['id']
```